# Algorithm to find best option

Tags: algorithm

I have multiple key:value and need to find the best possible option.

| Product | Price | Product | Price | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| label1 | 11 | label2 | 12 | label3 | 13 |
| label4 | 14 | label5 | 15 | label6 | 16 |

I need to find all possible options starting from the first column
and find best solution like an example:

| Product | Price | Product | Price | Product | Price | SUM | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| label1 | 11 | label2 | 12 | label3 | 13 | 36 |  |
| label1 | 11 | label2 | 12 | label6 | 16 | 39 |  |
| label1 | 11 | label5 | 15 | label3 | 13 | 39 |  |
| label1 | 11 | label5 | 15 | label6 | 16 | 42 |  |
| label4 | 14 | label5 | 15 | label6 | 16 | 45 | label4-label5-label6 |
| label4 | 14 | label5 | 15 | label3 | 13 | 42 |  |
| label4 | 14 | label2 | 12 | label3 | 13 | 39 |  |
| label4 | 14 | label2 | 12 | label6 | 16 | 42 |  |

Please, any language, I need to understand algorithm

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to maximize the sum and there is no constraint other than having only one item from each column. In that case: just take the item with the maximum value from each column.

Pseudo code:

```
res = []
for each col in cols:
  item = getMaxItem(col)
  res.push(item)

getMaxItem(col):
  item = col[0]
  for each i in col:
    if i.price > item.price:
      item = i
  return item
```

This would be an `O(n)` solution, with `n` being the number of items in all the columns.